# How to use my long (60day) access token to get user data from facebook (offline)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I cannot find any example on facebook dev. or here on stackoverflow so I need to make this post which i didn't thought i had to.

I have a website which uses the facebook JavaScript SDK to login users into it.
When I log in users I uses the

```
FB.login(), scope:{'email, offline_access'}
```

When the login in done i get the short lived access token and passes it to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    fb_exchange_token=SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

So i get the long lived, 60day, token in response. This is done server-side and i save the new long lasting token in my database along with facebook id etc.

Now to my problem. Every day at a certain time I want to update the users data in my database using the access token, which i have read that could. But how do i do that?

**I'm used to do like this after the FB.login() but now when the user do not login I don't know how to do the call to FB.api using my persisted token?**

```
FB.api(/me....)
```

Regards,
Kristoffer

Comment: `offline_access` does not exist any more, so don’t ask for it. And if you want to update a database, then I assume we are talking about something server-side here – so why would you use FB.api for that?

Comment: Ok, I know its deprecated but was not sure if I still needed it. Will remove it then

Answer (score 1):

As you have to synchronize/update information when user is not logged in you will have to use server side interaction.
You may use your saved [Extended Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) and set it into [Facebook PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) using [setAccessToken()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/) method.

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($extended_access_token);
```

After this you may call **$facebook->api(...)** method to perform the task that you intend to.

Comment: I'm not using PHP as server language though. I'm using Scala with Play framework. Any idea´s how to solve that?

Comment: The first link explains how to extend a short-lived user access token via the API – what language you implement it in doesn’t matter.

Comment: I didn't have any problem extending the token. My problem was using it to get data from facebook but not from javascript nor PHP. I did found the correct URL to use to call the graph api though: http://graph.facebook.com/'facebookID'?access_token=xxxx...